# Dependency Injection and Generic Windows Forms C # Repository

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, inversion-of-control

I have a windows forms application where I am trying to use dependency injection for some services, so I did the following configuration initially in Program.cs I register the services:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(services);

        using (ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
        {
            var mainForm = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SelecionarEmpresa>();
            Application.Run(mainForm);
        }
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContext<AnalistDbContext>();

        services.AddSingleton<MainForm>();
        services.AddScoped<Form1>();
        services.AddScoped<Form2>();
        services.AddScoped<Form3>();

        services.AddTransient<IEmpRepository, EmpRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<ISisRepository, SisRepository>();
    }
}
```

So far everything working, there are 3 Forms I made to test the functionality, in Form1 I inject the services I need:

```
private readonly ISisRepository _sisRepository;
private readonly IEmpRepository _empRepository;
public Form1(ISisRepository sistRepository,
             IEmpRepository empRepository)
{
    _sisRepository= sistRepository;
    _empRepository = empRepository;

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

And the idea is to use, for example, _sisRepository to update a record, the first time I save it works, if I click to save again, an exception is raised, before putting the exception I already inform you that I am using a generic repository, which is the next:

```
public abstract class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity, new()
{
    protected readonly AnalistDbContext Db;
    protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;
    protected Repository(AnalistDbContext db)
    {
        Db = db;
        DbSet = db.Set<TEntity>();

        Db.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

        var existeBanco = (Db.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>() as RelationalDatabaseCreator).Exists();

        if (!existeBanco)
        {
            (Db.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>() as RelationalDatabaseCreator).Create();
            (Db.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>() as RelationalDatabaseCreator).CreateTables();
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Buscar(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(predicate).AsNoTracking().ToList();
    }

    public virtual TEntity ObterPorId(Guid id)
    {
        return DbSet.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
    }

    public virtual List<TEntity> ObterTodos()
    {
        return DbSet.AsNoTracking().ToList();
    }

    public void Adicionar(TEntity entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
        SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Atualizar(TEntity entity)
    {
        DbSet.Update(entity);
        SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Remover(Guid id)
    {
        DbSet.Remove(new TEntity { Id = id });
        SaveChanges();
    }
    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return Db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Db?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The exception is:

[image]

Despite the clarity of the message, I could not understand if this is a problem caused by the use of dependency injection in the Form's constructor and having caused some problem in relation to the repository instance, it seems that my object is still the same as instantiated earlier, because as I said, this error only occurs on the second call. If that is really the problem, how could you solve it? Or when it comes to windows forms, would I abandon the use of dependency injection?

Comment: Can you make it simpler to understand the problem? It is a bit hard to follow

Comment: Taking into account some answers, it seems to be a problem when I update a record a second time, as it seems to be already tracked, apparently I should recreate my context, otherwise I get the image of the above exception. 
But this is the problem, I would like to understand how to set this scenario up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you update an item, the DbContext starts tracking that item. When you do a second update, the same DbContext tries to track *another* item with *the same id*. It's not an issue with the dependency injection, it's an issue with the lifetime of the injected AnalistDbContext and the objects tracked by it.

Typically, a DbContext would be instantiated on a per-operation basis, instead of living for the duration of the entire form. This helps prevent inconsistencies when two users are trying to modify the same entity. You could try:

- Update Form1 to use a factory that can create repositories, and dispose the repository after using it
- Update Repository to use a factory that can create an AnalistDbContext, and dispose the context after using it

If you think you're going to be the only user updating the entry, and aren't worried about race conditions or anything like that, you can check if the entry is already being tracked by the db context before trying to attach it.

Comment: For the adjustment options, would you have an example idea for them? I tried some alternatives but to no avail.